# The import org.andengine.BuildConfig cannot be resolved, can't install AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine, adt

I have a problem with instalation AndEngine GLS2, this row

```
   import org.andengine.BuildConfig;
```

show mistake "import org.andengine.BuildConfig;" I read forums but there wrotte that:
for last AndEngine GLS2 u need ADT 17. But I use last ADT 21, but nevertheless it shows this mistake can you say me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this the other day when updating my version of eclipse.  BuildConfig should be generated automatically, you shouldn't need to find or create that class.  Restarting Eclipse and selecting Project --> Clean fixed it for me.  If that's still not working, you may have to simply do a clean install of AndEngine.